# JSTL i18n fmt properties setup

Tags: jsp, internationalization, jstl, resourcebundle

Trying to use JSTL to have an i18n app, I have this:

```
<li><a href="admin/insertEmployee.jsp"><fmt:message key="new"/></a></li>
```

But on browser it does not translate the correspondent key 'new' and displays `???new???` instead of value defined in properties file as an HTML anchor (should be 'Novo', in pt_PT).

I have the following files under a package:

- messages.properties
- messages_en_US.properties
- messages_pt_Pt.properties.

Tried to define a default locale inside web.xml (pt_PT), but still not working...

Do I need to define a `<fmt:setLocale />`?
Is this the correct URI:
`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>`

In *web.xml*:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>
        javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext
    </param-name>
    <param-value>com.arthurportas-i18n.messages</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>
        javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.fallbackLocale
    </param-name>
    <param-value>pt_PT</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>
        javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.locale
    </param-name>
    <param-value>pt_PT</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @arthur-portas: Only strange behavior is that selecting english translation through clicking on link, requires double click!! A single click is ignored...Is this a browser cache behavior?

That's because you set the locale after the setBundle. the correct order is:

```
<c:if test="${param['lang'] !=null}">
    <fmt:setLocale value="${param['lang']}" scope="session" />
</c:if>
<fmt:setBundle basename="com.arthurportas.i18n.Messages"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved:
I defined default locale pt_PT in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>
        javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.locale
    </param-name>
    <param-value>
        pt_PT
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

and inside index.jsp, code to declare resource bundle and overriding locale if provided by url as a parameter(example-> /?lang=en_US)

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>

<fmt:setBundle basename="com.arthurportas.i18n.Messages"/>
<c:if test="${param['lang'] !=null}">
    <fmt:setLocale value="${param['lang']}" scope="session" />
</c:if>
```

used scope="session", applying to all jps's.
The presentation link to change language(english)

```
<a href="?lang=en_US"><img src="img/UKFlag_32_32.png"></img></a>
```

and i have two files under package com.arthurportas.i18n:
Messages_pt_PT.properties and Messages_en_US.
Inside jsp files text translated using for example:

```
<fmt:message key="employee"/>
```

Only strange behavior is that selecting english translation through clicking on link, requires double click!! A single click is ignored...Is this a browser cache  behavior?